# ObservableCollection via ListCollectionView displays incorrect list of items

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, listcollectionview

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ViewModel();

        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.Models.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public ListCollectionView View { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
        {
            new Model() { Name = "Gordon Freeman" },
            new Model() { Name = "Isaac Kleiner" },
            new Model() { Name = "Eli Vance" },
            new Model() { Name = "Alyx Vance" },
        };

        Models.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => View.Refresh();
        View = new ListCollectionView(Models);
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=View}" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Click</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

The ObservableCollection contains 4 elements, and the ListBox is displaying all 4, as expected.  When the button is clicked, the  1st element of the ObservableCollection is removed.  The ListBox, however, is now displaying only the 2nd and 3rd.  It would appear the 1st and 4th have been removed.

If the line `Models.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => View.Refresh();` is moved *after* `View = new ListCollectionView(Models);` (or commented out entirely) things work as expected.

Why?

P.S. This is a simple piece of a larger puzzle.  In this small example, I realize I don't need to call `View.Refresh();` on CollectionChanged for the ListBox to update itself.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the refresh interferes with the automatic update by the view. Presumably the view subscribes to `CollectionChanged` as well in the constructor, so if you also subscribe to the event before the view does and call refresh you get an unwanted update in between the collection change and the view's own update.

e.g.

Item 0 is removed -> Notify event listeners
 => Your handler: Refresh() -> Rebuild view => Item gets removed.
 => View handler: Event args say: Item X was removed -> Remove item X

This still does not explain why the first and the last items get removed but it seems reasonable to me.

If the subscription is after the view instantiation:

Item 0 is removed -> Notify event listeners
 => View handler: Event args say: Item X was removed -> Remove item X
 => Your handler: Refresh() -> Rebuild view => Nothing changed.

Comment: This sounds right, but I guess we don't really know for sure...why would the LAST item be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with ListView refresh. If you bind a labe/TextBlock to ListView.Items.Count, you'll see that the list still has 3 items (after first delete).

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're wrapping your `Model` class in an `ObservableCollection`, you still need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it.  I've banged my head against this problem enough times that now I remember to start troubleshooting at the lowest building block, i.e. `Model`.

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotify Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public string _Name;
    public string Name {
        get { return _Name;  }
        set { _Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Also, in your `ViewModel`, when `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented correctly you don't need the below lines.  `INotifyPropertyChanged` will update your UI for you.

```
    Models.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => View.Refresh();
    View = new ListCollectionView(Models);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use the new keyword to define your new instance of `listCollectionView`. Use the following instead.

```
var sortedCities  = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Models);
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: CollectionViewSource keep track of all views of your Ilist collection. using new will  create a new instance of your collection view, and add it to the CollectionViewSource. Using GetDefaultView will give you a default view of your collection and protect your code from having multiple views. So you can add sort and filter on a single view.